# Find $\left \lfloor{(x+y)^4}\right \rfloor$ if $3x^2-2xy+3y^2-8y+6=0$.

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find $\left \lfloor{(x+y)^4}\right \rfloor$ if $3x^2-2xy+3y^2-8y+6=0$.

I'm pretty bad at algebra so I struggle with questions like these, and I have literally no idea how to get $\left \lfloor{(x+y)^4}\right \rfloor$ out of $3x^2-2xy+3y^2-8y+6=0$. I considered expressing $x$ in terms of $y$ (since the equation is a quadratic in $x$) but I don't see how that could help me. Maybe there's a clever factorization I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The solutions to the equation is actually just a single point.
We can determine this by calculating the various determinants:
$ AC  - \frac{B^2}{4} = 3 \times 3 -\frac{(-2)^2}/4 > 0 $ so we have an ellipse.
$\Delta =   (AC - \frac{B^2}{4} ) F + \frac{BED}{4} - \frac{CD^2}{4} - \frac{AE^2}{4} = 0 $ so it's a degenerate ellipse, namely a single point. (Note that $\Delta$ is the discriminant of Will's matrix.)

> $3x^2-2xy+3y^2-8y+6  = 2(x-y+1)^2 + (x+y-2)^2 \quad (1)   $
>  Hence, the expression = 0 iff $x-y+1 = 0, x + y - 2 = 0$, which is the point $ (1/2, 3/2)$.
>  Thus $(x+y)^4 = 16.$

---

Algorithm for calculating (1): Convert a conic section into standard form. This is shown in Steven's solution.

Comment: Thank you! How did you come up with the factorization?

Comment: Read up on conic sections and decomposing them into rectilinear coordinates.

Comment: Calvin, there is an elementary method using matrices; I got interested as the students have so much trouble with repeated completing the squares. Answer below and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: @WillJagy Yes of course, I just didn't think that OP knows how to think about this in terms of matrices. The fact that a symmetric matrix can be orthogonally diagonalizable gives the decomposition into rectilinear coordinates.

Comment: No orthogonal matrices, just quadratic forms. Lots of students would not be able to find your $2 A^2 + B^2.$ What I meant is an algorithm, taught in some countries but not usually in the U.S. , for constructing (symmetric rational $H$) $P^T H P = D$ for nonsingular $P$ with rational entries; with $Q = P^{-1}$ we get $Q^T D Q = H. $  Just pedagogical.

Comment: Students being unable to do it has more to do with how they don't form connections between the topics, esp if someone didn't explicitly tell them, which is a separate issue altogether. There is an algorithm to convert a conic section (2 variable quadratic form) into standard form (perpendicular axis) which involves a rotation through $cot 2\theta = \frac{3-3}{-2}=0$, $\theta = 45^\circ$, which gives exactly my equation. Admittedly, cross terms are often skipped by the time the teacher gets to it. This is just pedagogical too.

Comment: Steven's solution presents the calculations that I went through. As an aside, it is very helpful to treat quadratic inequality (in many variables) as a quadratic form, and converting it into a/any diagonalizable matrix, which helps to demystify the "how on earth did you complete that square".

Answer (score 0):

Your polynomial is
$$ 3 \left(x - \frac{y}{3} \right)^2 + \frac{8}{3} \left(y - \frac{3}{2} \right)^2 = 0  $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$3x^2-2xy+3y^2-8y+6=0$$

We can eliminate the $xy$ term by rotating the axis through an angle of $\theta$ where 
$$\cot(2\theta) = \dfrac{a-c}{b} = \dfrac{3-3}{-2}= 0$$

The simplest solution is $2\theta = 90^\circ$. So $\theta = 45^\circ$.

So
$$\left(
   \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} 
  \right) =
  \left(\begin{array}{c} 
      \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
      \sin \theta & \cos \theta
   \end{array} \right)
   \left(
   \begin{array}{c} u \\ v \end{array} 
  \right) =
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\begin{array}{c} 
      1 & -1 \\
      1 & 1
   \end{array} \right)
   \left(
   \begin{array}{c} u \\ v \end{array} 
  \right)=
\left(
   \begin{array}{c}
      \dfrac{u- v}{\sqrt 2} \\ 
      \dfrac{u + v}{\sqrt 2} \end{array} 
  \right)$$

substituting and simplifying, we get

$$\begin{align}
   2 u^2 - 4 \sqrt 2 u + 4 v^2 - 4 \sqrt 2 v + 6 &= 0 \\
   2(u^2 - 2 \sqrt 2 u) + 4 v^2 - 4 \sqrt 2 v + 6 &= 0 \\
   2(u^2 - 2 \sqrt 2 u + 2) + (4 v^2 - 4 \sqrt 2 v + 2) &= 0 \\
   2(u - \sqrt 2)^2 +(2v-\sqrt 2)^2 = 0
\end{align}$$

So $u = \sqrt 2$ and $v = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.

It follows that $x = \dfrac 12$ and $y = \dfrac 32$

$$(x+y)^4 = 2^4=16$$